# Confusion over RLP encoding for byte array > 55 bytes

Tags: rlp

I am reading through the wiki on RLP (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) and think I am missing something fundamental.

For byte arrays (not lists) greater than 55 bytes, the RLP encoding is `0xb7` plus the length in bytes of the byte array in binary form, plus the length of the byte array plus the byte array.

Is there a difference between the length in binary form and the length in general?  I would assume they are the same?  Is this a typo, or am I missing something fundamental?

The wiki actually uses the term string instead of byte array, but since they are interchangable I though it more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just once the length of the byte array - the wiki describes it a bit confusing. Better look at the yellowpaper PDF (appendix RLP):

https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Or an implementation:
  https://github.com/walleth/kethereum/blob/master/rlp/src/main/java/org/kethereum/functions/rlp/RLPFun.kt#L24

Comment: Nice little bit of sunday reading :)

Comment: Enjoy - and always happy about constructive comments of the kotlin implementation